# I have an external JSON and wish to style it on my website

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to learn how to turn a remote json dataset into a html page.

I have acquired the full exported json into this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ZWUhZKPD

The reason I have done this is so that I don't expose any access tokens to the json.

Each set as far as i can tell is like this:

```
{
        "date": "2021-01-26",
        "venue": "Mayplace Road East",
        "competition": {
          "name": "Isthmian League - South East Division",
          "id": 40
        },
        "id": 367714,
        "time": "19:45",
        "home-team": {
          "score": 0,
          "name": "Phoenix Sports",
          "id": 1549
        },
        "away-team": {
          "score": 0,
          "name": "Hastings United",
          "id": 260
        },
        "attendance": 0,
        "status": {
          "short": "7.45pm",
          "full": "Kick off 7.45pm"
        }
},
```

This is the HTML output that I would like:

```
<h6>{date here}, {status->full here}</h6>
    <div class="latest_results_col"><img src="{home-team->name here}.png"><span>{home-team->name here}</span></div>
    <div class="latest_results_col goalscore2">vs</div>
    <div class="latest_results_col"><img src="{away-team->name here}.png" /><span>{away-team->name here}</span></div>
    <div class="clear">
    <span>Location: {venue here}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But no matter what I try it doesnt seem to work. I tried the foreach command but I get the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

I am not expecting anyone to write the entire code, i don't have the funds to pay someone to do it and it is also something I would really like to learn how to do, JSON is a new venture for me, away from databases and such.

Every page I have visited explains how to do it using a local json, but for some reason the output I have doesn't mirror that they show.

I really appreciate any help given to me and if you have any links of webpages that can help me understand it please post them.

EDIT:
I have been asked to provide code, this is what I have tried.

```
<?php

'the variable i set the json to is $json'

$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json_decoded[0]['home-team'];

?>
```

that was just me trying to get the home-team name displayed.

I think I need to learn and understand arrays and how to get data from them because I know I am not doing it right, and this is why I have come here, because I am struggling to understand.

EDIT 2:
Okay I think I know what I need to learn, that sounds very irish, but looking at the array there seems to be multiple arrays within.

So what i need to do is get data from the main array, in this case the main array is in $json, then there is a sub array called 'matches', and then in there is where each set is so for instance i need to access "$json->matches->home-team['name']" but I am sure that is the incorrect way to access the data within the array.

So the question then becomes in the example above how do I access the home-team name "Phoenix Sports" so its outputted?

Comment: Everything you need is inside `$json_decoded['fixtures-results']['matches'][0...41]`. So the home team name of match 0 would be retrieved with `$json_decoded['fixtures-results']['matches'][0]['home-team']['name']`

Comment: Michel how would I then tell it to do it for each one? is that the foreach?

Comment: Yes, just foreach. I'd suggest making a function with a template. I'll write you an example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json gives an array

```
[
 fixtures-results=>
    [
    team =>[some data],
    matches =>[
      0 =>[ match data ],
      1 =>[ match data ],
      2 =>[ match data ],
     ...
      41 => [match data ]
    ]
]
```

You can output the decode array to the screen with `echo '<pre>'.print_r($json_decoded,true);`

so displaying the match data could be done by:

```
foreach ( $json_decoded['fixtures-results']['matches'] as $match){ 
   display_match($match);
   }

function display_match($match){
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<h6>'.$match['date'].','.$match['status']['full'].'</h6>';
  echo '<div class="latest_results_col">
        <img src="'.$match['home-team']['name'].'.png">
        <span>'.$match['home-team']['name'].'</span>
        </div>';
     etc...
  echo '</div>';
  }
```